# Make sbt recompile affected Java sources

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I am using sbt in a mixed Java/Scala project. Unfortunately, sbt does not seem to do any dependency analysis for Java sources. E.g., if `A.java` depends on `B.java` and I change `B.java`, it doesn't bother to recompile `A.java`. I guess this is a bug, but I need a workaround for this.

The only solution is to do `clear compile` which sucks because it will wipe my javadocs and sources in the IDEA project. I also tried to open a bash and run `rm -r target/classes/`, but that's even worse. Sbt still doesn't see it needs to recompile the Java sources and only complains that these classes do not exist when I refer to them from Scala.

Is there a trick to force sbt to recompile all Java sources?

---

**Edit**: To reproduce:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Sciss/TreeTable.git
...
$ cd TreeTable
$ git checkout 00daa4288574b658c8bb643cb2ddf9768195c50a
$ sbt compile
```

This will compile the project. sbt will crash at some point:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/hhrutz/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/hhrutz/Desktop/sbtprob/TreeTable/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/hhrutz/Desktop/sbtprob/TreeTable/project/}treetable-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/hhrutz/Desktop/sbtprob/TreeTable/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
[info] Set current project to TreeTable (in build file:/Users/hhrutz/Desktop/sbtprob/TreeTable/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/hhrutz/Desktop/sbtprob/TreeTable/}treetable-java...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/Users/hhrutz/Desktop/sbtprob/TreeTable/}treetable-scala...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-swing;2.10.2 ...
[info] Compiling 29 Java sources to /Users/hhrutz/Desktop/sbtprob/TreeTable/java/target/classes...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/Users/hhrutz/Desktop/sbtprob/TreeTable/}treetable...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[warn] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[warn] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.error(SignatureParser.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseSimpleClassTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:262)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseClassTypeSignatureSuffix(SignatureParser.java:270)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseClassTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:244)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseFieldTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:228)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:359)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseReturnType(SignatureParser.java:490)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseMethodTypeSignature(SignatureParser.java:436)
    at sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser.parseMethodSig(SignatureParser.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.parse(ConstructorRepository.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.parse(ConstructorRepository.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.AbstractRepository.<init>(AbstractRepository.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.GenericDeclRepository.<init>(GenericDeclRepository.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ConstructorRepository.<init>(ConstructorRepository.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.<init>(MethodRepository.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.make(MethodRepository.java:41)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericInfo(Method.java:94)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getTypeParameters(Method.java:196)
    at sbt.ClassToAPI$.methodToDef(ClassToAPI.scala:143)
    at sbt.ClassToAPI$$anonfun$7.apply(ClassToAPI.scala:73)
    at sbt.ClassToAPI$$anonfun$7.apply(ClassToAPI.scala:73)
    at sbt.ClassToAPI$$anonfun$mergeMap$1.apply(ClassToAPI.scala:175)
    at sbt.ClassToAPI$$anonfun$mergeMap$1.apply(ClassToAPI.scala:175)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
    at sbt.ClassToAPI$.merge(ClassToAPI.scala:181)
    at sbt.ClassToAPI$.mergeMap(ClassToAPI.scala:175)
    at sbt.ClassToAPI$.structure(ClassToAPI.scala:73)
    at sbt.ClassToAPI$.x$2$lzycompute$1(ClassToAPI.scala:62)
    at sbt.ClassToAPI$.x$2$1(ClassToAPI.scala:62)
    at sbt.ClassToAPI$.instance$lzycompute$1(ClassToAPI.scala:62)
    at sbt.ClassToAPI$.sbt$ClassToAPI$$instance$1(ClassToAPI.scala:62)
    at sbt.ClassToAPI$$anonfun$5.apply(ClassToAPI.scala:63)
    at sbt.ClassToAPI$$anonfun$5.apply(ClassToAPI.scala:63)
    at xsbti.SafeLazy$Impl._t$lzycompute(SafeLazy.scala:20)
    at xsbti.SafeLazy$Impl._t(SafeLazy.scala:18)
    at xsbti.SafeLazy$Impl.get(SafeLazy.scala:24)
    at sbt.ClassToAPI$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ClassToAPI.scala:22)
    at sbt.ClassToAPI$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ClassToAPI.scala:22)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at sbt.ClassToAPI$.process(ClassToAPI.scala:22)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$$readAPI$1(AggressiveCompile.scala:130)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:138)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:138)
    at sbt.classfile.Analyze$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Analyze.scala:45)
    at sbt.classfile.Analyze$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Analyze.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at sbt.classfile.Analyze$.apply(Analyze.scala:43)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:138)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:136)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2.apply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:136)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:136)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileJava$1$2.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:136)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$timed(AggressiveCompile.scala:159)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.compileJava$1(AggressiveCompile.scala:135)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:142)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:86)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:38)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:36)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.cycle(Incremental.scala:73)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:33)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:32)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:41)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:32)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:26)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile2(AggressiveCompile.scala:150)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile1(AggressiveCompile.scala:70)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:45)
    at sbt.Compiler$.apply(Compiler.scala:70)
    at sbt.Defaults$.sbt$Defaults$$compileTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:722)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:716)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:716)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Run again to finish compilation:

```
$ sbt compile
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/hhrutz/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/hhrutz/Desktop/sbtprob/TreeTable/project
[info] Set current project to TreeTable (in build file:/Users/hhrutz/Desktop/sbtprob/TreeTable/)
[info] Compiling 29 Java sources to /Users/hhrutz/Desktop/sbtprob/TreeTable/java/target/classes...
[warn] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[warn] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[info] Compiling 8 Scala sources to /Users/hhrutz/Desktop/sbtprob/TreeTable/scala/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[success] Total time: 20 s, completed Dec 11, 2013 4:06:48 PM
```

Ok. Now make an edit.

```
$ vi java/src/main/java/de/sciss/treetable/j/ui/TreeTableUI.java
```

For example change in line 35 from `DefaultTreeTableCellRenderer renderer` to `TreeTableCellRenderer renderer`. Save and exit vi.

Run compilation again:

```
$ sbt compile
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/hhrutz/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/hhrutz/Desktop/sbtprob/TreeTable/project
[info] Set current project to TreeTable (in build file:/Users/hhrutz/Desktop/sbtprob/TreeTable/)
[info] Compiling 1 Java source to /Users/hhrutz/Desktop/sbtprob/TreeTable/java/target/classes...
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Dec 11, 2013 4:08:40 PM
```

Obviously it did only recompile `TreeTableUI.java`, whereas the implementing class `BasicTreeTableUI` is now corrupt and would need recompilation. The only way to force recompilation is to clean the project.

Comment: A test case is probably necessary.  At a minimum the relevant parts of the build definition configuring the dependency, including the sbt version, are helpful.  Java sources are incrementally compiled to the extent that dependency information is in class files (for example, sbt can't know about inlined constants because they aren't in class files).  Incremental compilation should certainly handle Java sources and mixed projects otherwise.

Comment: @MarkHarrah - I attached a test case. Perhaps the problem is produced by the transitory compiler crash, I don't know. If I compile the java sources with `javac`, it doesn't crash, so this is not a problem of my java installation.

Comment: BTW, unrelated. I noticed this annoying `Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...` recently in virtually every project of mine. Any clue where that comes from, and why it is checking it out 5 (!) times?!

Comment: Yes, the problem is with the crash.  javac succeeds, but when sbt loads the class files in order to extract dependency information, Java reflection fails.  It isn't clear whether that is a bug in Java reflection or `javac` or possibly sbt.  Please open a bug on sbt for now.

Comment: What _version_ of Java you are using? Maybe you are producing class files in a format that the version of Java in which sbt is running doesn't understand?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral `1.6.0_65` (latest for OS X 10.6); filed [bug](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1035)

Comment: Can we close this question since Mark fixed #1035?

Comment: @EugeneYokota - I guess so. Just paste an answer with a link to that ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP filed [sbt#1035: 
java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError when compiling Java sources](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1035), which was fixed by Mark in 0.13 branch, and it's now available as sbt 0.13.2.

Comment: Ah alright, I did file the bug, sorry my memory is a Swiss cheese.